# Read Data From Port Using UDP Protocol In Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, udp, port

I'm New in Vb.net and I have got stuck with one problem.
I don't know how can I read data from UDP port continuously.
I am getting stream of bytes over my port and i want to read data from port and store it In queue so that I can process the received data accordingly.

help me.
suggest me how to do???

Sample codes are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is read the data from the port on a different (non blocking) thread.

[This example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8877/UDP-Send-and-Receive-using-threads-in-VB-NET) on code project is a complete working example on how to do this

Comment: I have tried it,but its not working in my code, i want to read bytes from stream and store it in queue and use the store data in queue for decoding it further.(I'm reading TS stream)

Comment: The link I posted is a complete working example - what is it that isn't working?